# How to remove hamburger menu icon on MasterDetailPage but keep navigation bar

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to remove the hamburger menu (for drawer to open/close) but keep the navigation bar and back icon if there a stack. I am struggling to find a solution for this.

Doing this will totally remove the navigation bar

```
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"
```

I want only the icon to be removed.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? The MasterDetailPage is designed to have one... Maybe you should just switch to NavigationPage?

Comment: @fredrik we have a custom bottom tab page which consist also of menu icon. having the top menu icon is redundant in our design

Comment: Then afaik you have to disable the navigation bar as a whole. If you still need one, place a NavigationPage in the MasterDetailPage.Detail and put all navigation items there.

Comment: but i also need a bar on the top @fredrik

Comment: @fredrik I also need a navigation bar on top, only removing the menu icon is what I want

Comment: A `NavigationPage` has a bar on the top, last I looked. You will have to place everything you need on that navigation page instead of on the masterdetailpage. as far as I know - it's your only option.

Comment: Bit difficult to type out in 1 answer... so best I link to the GitHub repository - https://github.com/Depechie/2018-XamarinOutOfTheBox we had the same kind of issue and are now rendering the navigation bar completely in XAML instead of using the build in one. Try to see if the repository makes sense?

Comment: @Depechie if you can point out what file will I check the better.

Comment: We use a BasePage ( https://github.com/Depechie/2018-XamarinOutOfTheBox/blob/master/XFAppTemplate/Views/BasePage.xaml#L29 ) that has all icons needed and depending on what type of page you load, we switch the icon ( or hide it ) https://github.com/Depechie/2018-XamarinOutOfTheBox/blob/master/XFAppTemplate/Views/BasePage.xaml.cs#L90

Comment: Ha I forgot, I explained this all at a conference earlier this year and it's recorded :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3UfQX78qNI&t=1081s

Comment: You can do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47297619/1341538 but instead of changing the icon just hide it. Or replace it with a transparent image.

Comment: @SecretCoder Did you find a way to do this? I'm trying for the same thing

Comment: @ledragon I know it is an old question. Does my post answers your question? Please let me know whether it is working for you or no.

Comment: Any feedback on this post?

Comment: @Cfun I am not currently working on this project now so I cannot give you a feedback on this.

Answer (score 3):

I know it is an old question, but in your case it is better to use [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#flyout-behavior). You can hide the hamburger button and implicitly disable the flyout menu using:

- Globally inside AppShell (or whatever named)

```
<Shell>
...
     FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
..
</Shell>
```

- Or hide it only in a single page

```
<ContentPage>
...
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
</ContentPage>
```