# How change icon for MasterDetail on Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I have Xamarin Forms. I need change standard icon for `MasterDetailPage`. Property Icon do not working on Android. I tried add custom renderer, but it don't work.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MainPage), typeof(IconNavigationPageRenderer))]
namespace masterDe.Droid
{
    public class IconNavigationPageRenderer : MasterDetailPageRenderer
    {
        public IconNavigationPageRenderer(Context context):base(context) { }
        private static Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar GetToolbar() => (CrossCurrentActivity.Current?.Activity as MainActivity)?.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);


        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
            var toolbar = GetToolbar();
            if (toolbar != null)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < toolbar.ChildCount; i++)
                {
                    var imageButton = toolbar.GetChildAt(i) as Android.Widget.ImageButton;

                    var drawerArrow = imageButton?.Drawable as DrawerArrowDrawable;
                    if (drawerArrow == null)
                        continue;

                    // replace default hamburg icon
                    imageButton.SetImageDrawable(Forms.Context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.icon));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`GetToolbar()` always is null. How Can I fix it?

Comment: I don't think you need a custom renderer for that, did you try to add something like this `IconImageSource="hamburger.png"` on your master page ? Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/flyoutpage#create-the-flyout-page) about it.

Answer (score 1):

I tested on my side based on your code, but it works properly on my side.

You can recheck if you have installed  and set up nuget [Plugin.CurrentActivity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.CurrentActivity) correctly on android platform.

And call the Init method on `OnCreate`:

```
CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);
```

For more about this, check: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin .

In addition, you can check if you have layout `Toolbar.axml` in folder `layout`, the code is like this:

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

The result is:

[image]

Note: you can refer to this thread: [Change hamburger icon in master detail navigation xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47286597/change-hamburger-icon-in-master-detail-navigation-xamarin-forms) .